# Using Pareto Principle (80/20), How to calculate the true percentage if given an input between 0-100

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

Loosely based on a the Pareto/80-20 principle, in terms of if I think I am 70% done, according to Pareto, how "done" am I exactly? I'm expecting an answer around 15% in this example.

I want to be able to have a text input or a slider where I can have the input as 0-100%, so how can I take the input and transform it after Pareto?

Comment: Pareto was an economist, and said that 20% of the users account for 80% of the resource usage. You seem to be dealing with done-ness, to which the Pareto principle doesn't really apply.

Comment: Ah right. I feel like it does apply (in terms of doneness). I'm prepared to take the idea with a pinch of salt. (Edited OP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a silly idea but it's fun to think about.

Given a value of 'done' x between 0 and 1, the formula for 'Pareto-done' y is

> y = 20% ^ ( log (x) / log(80%) )

So in your example x=70% done gives y=7.6% Pareto-done.

Comment: Thank you. In my PHP: `pow(0.2,(log($input) / log(0.8)));`

Comment: Or `pow($input, log(0.2)/log(0.8))`, where `log(0.2)/log(0.8)` ≈ `7.2`

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution for the distribution that you're looking for.

Note that software development time estimates don't look like this.  When asked for estimates, people and organizations tend to consistently overestimate by a relatively constant factor.  (Not infrequently around 2.)  See *Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art* for more.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I am no mathematician. I was hoping for a jolly looking piece of code like: $output = $input * (something) / (something else). I've underestimated this it seems!